# Mongoose ODM findOneAndUpdate sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have a **Message** schema which has a sub-document of replies as such:

```
message: String,
replies: [{
   message: String,
   userFrom: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
   }
 }]
```

I am attempting to make a POST request that will allow me to findOneAndUpdate the message to attach a reply. I've attempted the following:

```
Message.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id,{
  replies: {
    message: req.body.reply,
    userFrom: req.user._id
  }
}, function(err, data){
  ...
});
```

What is happening is I am overwriting any reply that is currently in the replies array. I believe I need to use the $push operator but I'm not quite sure how.

Is it possible to use findOneAndUpdate as well as $push in a single request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were in the right direction. Using the following **[syntax](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)**

```
query.findOneAndUpdate(id, update, callback) // executes
```

you can do your update with the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator as follows:

```
var reply = {
    message: req.body.reply, 
    userFrom: req.user._id
};

Message.findOneAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    { $push: { replies: reply } },
    { upsert: true }, // upsert looks to find a Message with that id and if it doesn't exist creates the Message 
    function(err, data) {
        // Handle err
});
```